# Arabic text rendering with Skia (SkiaSharp)

Tags: arabic, skia, skiasharp

I'm rendering text with SkiaSharp for various platforms. I have problem with arabic script. I've created simple shaping routine and I have nicely connected glyphs. But diacritics is off completely.[image]

Is there an easy way how to render/position diacritics? Like another table, which tells that after this char, put this glyph which represent diacritics in middle position, or something like that.

I'have tried HarfBuzzSharp, it's working ok, except Android (where it is returning zeros to all glyph positions).

Comment: Ok, solved, I've found workaround how to make HarfBuzzSharp working on Xamarin.Android.

Comment: How did get it to work on android?

Comment: @Diaa Eddin  What have you problem with? Ask a question here